# Error when trying to add data to vector inside structure

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I am trying to add some data from a .txt file into a vector which is inside a structure, but the vector will not compile. The code is as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    vector<double> xAxis[100];
    vector<double> yAxis[100];
} AxisValues;

void startup()
{
    cout << "Numerical Integrator - calculating area under a curve.\n\n";
    cout << "Enter the name of the file which contains data points (x and y coordinates) that form the curve:\n";
}

void inputVal()
{
    AxisValues aValues;
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, n3 = 0, n4 = 0, n5 = 0, n6 = 0, n7 = 0, n8 = 0;
    string fileName;
    ifstream infile;

    cin >> fileName; //enter curve_s1.txt here

    infile.open(fileName);
    if (infile.fail()) { cout << "ERROR: FILE NOT DETECTED\n\n"; }

    for (n1 = 0; n1 < 10; n1++)
    {
        infile >> aValues.xAxis[n2];
        n2++;
        for (n3 = 0; n3 < 10; n3++);
        {
            infile >> aValues.yAxis[n4];
            n4++;
        }
    }

    cout << "x  y\n";
    for (n5 = 0; n5 < 10; n5++)
    {
        cout << aValues.xAxis[n6] << "  ";
        n6++;
        for (n7 = 0; n7 < 10; n7++);
        {
            cout << aValues.yAxis[n8] << "\n";
            n8++;
        }
    }
}

double trapezoidalRule(const double &x1, const double &x2, const double &y1, const double &y2)
{
    double result = 0;
    result = (x2 - x1)*((y1 + y2) / 2);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    startup();
    inputVal();
    //cout << trapezoidalRule(4, 5, 2, 3) << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following errors for this.

> E0349 no operator ">>" matches these operands E0349   no operator ">>"
>   matches these operands E0349  no operator "<<" matches these operands
>   E0349 no operator "<<" matches these operands
>
> C2679 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand
>   of type 'std::vector>' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)
>
> C2679 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand
>   of type 'std::vector>' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)
>
> C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand
>   of type 'std::vector>' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)
>
> Error C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'std::vector>' (or there is
>   no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Did you mean to have an array of 100 vectors?

Comment: `vector<double> xAxis[100];` defines an array of vectors not a single vector of size 100. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: oh okay sorry I don't know anything about c++11 ill delete my comment. thanks

Comment: You must try simpler exercises -- such as putting a number into a vector -- before you attempt something this complex.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make an vector which has size 100 you should type:

```
vector <int> vecName(100);
```

In this case you can use cin to add numbers from stream to vector like this(which you did in your code):

```
cin>>vecName[i];
```

But if you want Have 100 vectors you should type(which you did):

```
vector <int> vecName[100];
```

And you can add int by temporary variable like this:

```
int temp;
cin>>temp;
vecName[i].push_back(temp);
```

Your error comes from that you send integers to a vector not to an integer